# When is the twisted arrow category $\lambda$-cofiltered?

Tags: ct.category-theory

The twisted arrow category of $\cal C$ is the category of elements of $\hom_{\cal C}$.

> When is this category cofiltered?

This is equivalent to ask that the hom functor, taken as a presheaf on ${\cal C}^\text{op}\times \cal C$, commutes with finite limits, so

> When does $\hom_{\cal C}$ commute with finite lims?

Does it happen only in trivial cases?

Comment: E. g. if(f?) $\cal C$ has a zero object its tac has a terminal object, but you need the opposite direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that it only happens in trivial cases. Let me assume that $\mathcal{C}$ has binary products and coproducts. The functor $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}$ preserves products if and only if for all $A,A',B,B' \in \mathcal{C}$ the canonical map
$$\mathrm{Hom}(A+A',B  \times B') \longrightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(A,B)  \times \mathrm{Hom}(A',B')$$
is an isomorphism. However, the left hand side decomposes as
$$\mathrm{Hom}(A,B) \times \mathrm{Hom}(A,B') \times \mathrm{Hom}(A',B) \times \mathrm{Hom}(A',B')$$
and the canonical map is simply the projection. In particular, the projection
$\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)^4 \to \mathrm{Hom}(A,B)^2$ is injective, which shows that $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)$ has at most one element.  Thus, $\mathcal{C}$ is a preorder. The surjectivity of 
$$\mathrm{Hom}(A+A',A  \times A') \longrightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(A,A)  \times \mathrm{Hom}(A',A')$$
shows that $A+A' \leq A \times A'$, hence $A' \leq A$ for all $A,A'$. Thus, $\mathcal{C}$ is a trivial (codiscrete) preorder.

Comment: I think this resolves the problem and shows that this is too strong a condition. Thanks